# How can i open multiple web browser window without cookies?

Tags: browser

how can I open a new browser window without cookies ?
I mean, the window shouldn't remember the last session. If I log in to my google account and open new tabs or a new browser window, the browser will show me the same account again.

So, how can I solve this problem ? Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you check your skype account?